# How to do image fading with position relative?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to integrate the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179078/jquery-fading-effect-not-working-as-intended) to change image of my slide show on click (credit to `cssyphus`):

```js
$(function() {
  $("input:button").click(function() {
    $("img:last").fadeToggle("slow", function() {
      $(this).prependTo(".frame").fadeIn()
    });
  });
});

function Forward() {
  $("img:first").fadeToggle("slow", function() {
    $(this).appendTo(".frame").fadeIn(800)
  });
}

function Backward() {
  $("img:last").fadeToggle("slow", function() {
    $(this).prependTo(".frame").fadeIn()
  });
}
```

```css
.frame {
  position: relative;
  left: 35%;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
  <input type="button" value="PrependTo" />
  <button onclick="Forward()">Go Forward</button>
  <button onclick="Backward()">Go Backward</button>

</h1>
<div class="frame">
  <img src="http://placeimg.com/240/180/animals">
  <img src="http://placeimg.com/240/180/nature">
  <img src="http://placeimg.com/240/180/people">
  <img src="http://placeimg.com/240/180/sepia">
</div>
```

The issue arise due to the effect depending `position:absolute` to stack the images on top of one another.  Switching it to `position:relative` unstack the images and they are next to one another.  Using `position:absolute` throws off all other elements in the code to integrate into.  How can I remedy this problem?

Comment: Just change the position after Go Forward

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to imagine how the layout is affected by the slideshow, but from looking at your code I would try one of two things:

1. Remove the `left: 35%;` css from the `.frame` - I'm unsure why this is there but it will push the whole frame container of the slideshow over

   ```
   .frame {
       position: relative;
   }
   ```
2. Adjust the CSS for the `img` so it only affects the nth-children after the first one, so they will be stacked on top of one another while the first one is inherit/relative:

   ```
   img {
       position: relative;
   }
   img:nth-child(n+2) {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the for the pointer, @couchwood.  I will try it.  The `left: 35%;` is to position the image somewhere in the center.  It is just for test purpose.