# Footer section no longer centered after type change

Tags: html, css

I have a footer section which was previously defined in CSS as follows:

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.65;
  padding: 4em 0em 4em 1em; 
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;      
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

And in HTML as follows:

```
<footer>
....
</footer>
```

However, such setup makes dynamically positioning impossible with a jQuery command like this:

```
$("footer").css({'top': Top3 + "px",  });
```

So I change that command to:

```
$(".footer").css({'top': Top3 + "px",  });
```

And change the HTML to:

```
<div class="footer">
....
</div>
```

And the CSS to:

```
.footer {
  ...
}
```

The dynamic positioning works, but now my footer is no longer centered.  It is left-centered somehow, and only cover a portion of the width. Why might this be?

Comment: Can you share your files

Comment: What do you mean *no longer centered*? The `text-align` in your css is set to `left`

Comment: What is the purpose of this “dynamic positioning” in the first place, and what exactly about this “setup” makes it “impossible” …? This completely lacks any context that would be required for it to even start making some sense. Please go read [ask] and  [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata, adding `width:100%;` fixed it.  I thought `max-width: 100%;` already does the trick.  `text-align: left;` is meant for nested elements in this footer section.  Leaving it as is is just fine.

Comment: @04FS, my code has so many things in it.  I did not include the files worrying the details may distract people from the question.  Dynamic positioning is used in order to implement a fading effect, which relies on `position:absolute;` as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179078/jquery-fading-effect-not-working-as-intended).

Comment: Whatever you say, the problem has been fixed with the info I provided.  It is behind me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add  `width:100%;` to the .footer  and as mentioned above by  Chibueze Opata  the text-align as center

```js
$(".footer").css({'top': 0 + "px",  });
```

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.65;
  padding: 4em 0em 4em 1em; 
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;      
  max-width: 100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div class="footer">
 Hi there .. 
</div>
```

Comment: Adding `width:100%;` fixed it.  Thank you so much!